# Create Windows Service and capture touch events Win7 c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, windows-services, multi-touch

I would like help to create a Windows service that can listen for Multi-touch event occurances, intercept them and then just do something with them (not important).
I also need to know how to send Windows Messages to this service and the code to be able to receive those messages from within the service.

Anyone have any idea's at all please?

I've been cutting code for 15 years but have never written a Windows Service before and use a little help to get on my way :(

Comment: There is absolutely **no** reason for you to write this as a Windows Service. Write a standard user-mode application just like you've been doing all these years. Services are not just user-mode applications that run all the time in the background. If you want that, just create an app that runs in the background.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Please could you explain how that app, I'm guessing running window/form-less would receive Windows Messages?

Comment: Ah, perhaps I finally understand your question. It *sounds* like what you need is a **[message-only window](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632599.aspx#message_only)**. You would create this in a standard application (not a service), and you would still be able to send/receive messages, but an actual window would never be displayed on the screen. It would just run in the background.

Comment: Thanks Cody. This is the situation. We have an app (EXE) already that let's just say for arguments sake we can't change the code but we can tell it to send out a Windows Message (WM) to a specific Window/App when the user does certain things. Say the user slides the slider to change the volume... I need an app or whatever to run hidden in the background to listen for those messages and then interact with the Windows API to change the volume. I've already got all that code in a DLL I've written, I just need really to know how to write an app to receive those messages.........

Comment: .....(and how to send would be handy). I've looked in to WndProc(ref Message m) and I think that's what's needed in the background app, but I can't seem to get it working. Do you know of any similar examples on 'tineternet already, or could you help with one please?

Answer (score 1):

By definition, Windows Services are not supposed to be user-interactive, therefore, if you want to get the multi-touch data, you will have to hook directly into the operating system input messages using a [WM_TOUCH](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd317341%28VS.85%29.aspx) windows hook and interpreting that data yourself.

Comment: Thank you for that. So say I create this hook and that's capturing the touch events fine. How do I - for example set this Windows Service to be able to receive Windows Messages from other Apps? For example, say my WS had functionality to change the Windows brigtness and that function was SetBrightness(int brightnessLevel) what code/functionality would I have to add to my Windows Service to handle that please?

Comment: The first phrase of this answer is correct. The rest is nonsense. If deleted, this would be worth an upvote. Services are not intended to be interactive; the end.

Comment: @Cody If you see my comment above, please could you explain how I could achieve that either through a windows service or some other means which accepts windows messages?

Comment: @Kevin: Neither services nor applications can receive notifications intended for other applications. Your only option is to install a global system hook, which is an extremely heavy approach and probably not recommended. Those other applications have to forward their private messages to your app if you want to be notified and react accordingly. If you want to create an application that changes brightness based upon touch input, then you need to write a regular app that the user can interact with, specify a pattern for changing the brightness, and write the code to implement it in whatever...

Comment: you choose to call the function. There's no reason to do this as a Windows Service, and in fact, as mentioned, it's never going to work properly as a service because services are *not* intended to interact with the user or receive user input. The fact that they *ever* could was a security hole that Vista finally patched. I still don't understand why you think that you need to write a Windows Service.

Answer (score 1):

For those interested, I decided to go down the route of a normal Windows Form application, and when the time comes to put it live the for will be invisible so will run in the 'background' when the other application I need it to communicate with starts.

I managed to get **WndProc(ref Message m)** working and messages are being received by my app and its doing what it needs to do according to the instructions it's sent.

For example, the visible App has a GUI Slider for volume control. When the slider is moved the value of that slider is sent to my 'background' app via a Windows Message, and the 'background' App does the necessaries to change the Volume level of the device/PC, and when the volume level is requested, a Postback Message is sent to the requesting App to tell it what the Volume level is currently set at.

Some sample code below:-

```
public const int UI_VOLUME_SET = 1101;
    public const int UI_VOLUME_GET = 1100;
    public const int UI_VOLUME_SET_MUTE_STATUS = 1102;

    public const int UI_BRIGHT_GET = 1201;
    public const int UI_BRIGHT_SET = 1202;

    public const int UI_TERMINATE = 9999;

[System.Security.Permissions.PermissionSet(System.Security.Permissions.SecurityAction.Demand, Name = "FullTrust")]Protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        int _exoUI = MessageHelper.FindWindow(null, "MY UI");
        EXOxtenderLibrary.VolumeControl _vol;
        switch (m.Msg)
        {
            case UI_TERMINATE:
                this.Close();
                break;
            case UI_BRIGHT_GET:
                //ADD CODE HERE
                break;

            //case UI_BRIGHT_SET:
            //    //ADD CODE HERE
            //    break;

            case UI_VOLUME_GET:
                _vol = new EXOxtenderLibrary.VolumeControl();
                MessageHelper.PostMessage(_exoUI, 32773, _vol.GetVolume(), _vol.isMute);
                _vol = null;
                break;

            case UI_VOLUME_SET:
                _vol = new EXOxtenderLibrary.VolumeControl();
                _vol.SetVolume(m.WParam.ToInt32());
                MessageHelper.PostMessage(_exoUI, 32773, _vol.GetVolume(), _vol.isMute);
                _vol = null;
                break;

            case UI_VOLUME_SET_MUTE_STATUS:
                _vol = new EXOxtenderLibrary.VolumeControl();
                if (m.WParam == new IntPtr(1))
                { _vol.Mute = true; }
                else
                { _vol.Mute = false; }
                MessageHelper.PostMessage(_exoUI, 32773, _vol.GetVolume(), _vol.isMute);
                _vol = null;
                break;
        }

        base.WndProc(ref m);
    }
```